# Selenium and html agility pack drops html

Tags: html, selenium

I'm using the HTML Agility Pack and Selenium to crawl a site, find particular tables, and then parse those tables. Everything works fine individually, but when I run the app, it sometimes drops huge chunks of HTML from within the table. When I track down the page on the site with the data, the HTML is there. For whatever reason, it isn't there when the crawler is running.

Here's the code. The rows[r].InnerHtml is NOT the HTML from page. Anyone have any thoughts on what might be happening here?

```
public IMyInterface CreateObjectFromHtmlRow(HtmlNode rowNode)
{
    try
    {
    var columns = rowNode.SelectNodes("td");

    MyClass obj = new MyClass()
    {
        OnlineId = columns[0].InnerText.Trim(),
        FirstName = columns[1].InnerText.Trim(),
        MiddleInitial = columns[2].InnerText.Trim(),
        LastName = columns[3].InnerText.Trim(),
        Residence = columns[4].InnerText.Trim(),
    };
    return obj;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
    _logger.LogFormat("Error trying to parse row: {0}", exc.Message);
    return null;
    }
}

IMyInterface obj = null;
obj = _repository.CreateObjectFromHtmlRow(rows[r]);
if (obj == null)
{
    _logger.LogFormat("Unable to create object from this data: {0}", rows[r].InnerHtml);
}
else
{
    // Do something useful
}
```

Thanks for your help.

WW

Comment: Probably because HTMLAgilityPack is going to get the HTML that is there initially, and will not see any HTML or changes made by JS & AJAX requests. You are mixing things here. Selenium exposes the page source. Use that.

Comment: Arran, the HTML is coming from Selenium. That's the HTML passed into the HTML Agility Pack. Sorry, I thought that would be self explanatory.

Comment: Not really sure why you are using HTMLAgilityPack in the first place, Selenium works fine for web scraping. Let's see what website this is being run against

Comment: I can't share the site, that would violate my agreement with them. However, I can say that there is no JavaScript manipulating the DOM. I capture the page source using Selenium and then use HAP to find and parse the one (of many) table that I need from the page. There are tens of millions of rows being parsed and the rows that fail are seemingly random. I was multi-threaded, but I stopped that thinking it was the problem. That didn't work - still sometimes doesn't seem to get all of the html.